# How to prevent byte b'\x3f' from becoming b'?' when printed in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, byte

In a test I'm working on, I need to write byte string. 
Somehow python changes input `b'\x3f'` into `b'?'`. How can I prevent python from converting the escape code into a character and instead just print the hex value?

Comment: ```\x``` is an escape code, so when it prints, the ```\x3f``` is converted to a letter, ```0x3f``` just happens to be a ```?```

Comment: You could just do a replace before printing `print("\x3f".replace("\","\\"))`